# Target Display Mode between MacBook Pro and iMac won't work

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, thunderbolt, target-display

I try to use my iMac as a external screen or otherwise if possible, but when I press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> nothing happened. I also try <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> just to be sure

MacBook Pro 2012
iMac 27" 2012

Using Thunderbolt 2

Comment: Have you had a good look at [Use your iMac as a display with Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592)?

Comment: @Monomeeth yes, but I have done this before, but now I can't. that why I ask

Comment: How long has it been since this worked for you? And are you already logged into the MacBook Pro before trying to press Command-F2?

Comment: @Monomeeth I think is was in Yosemite. And yes I am logged in before press cmd + F2

Comment: Both the MBP 2012 and iMac 2012 have Thunderbolt 1 ports.  A TB2 cable *should* work, but I would take a look at that as well just to be sure.

Comment: Well i find out Why.... i just need to turn around the cabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i found out why... I just needed to turn the cable around. For some reason, the Thunderbolt cable can be plugged in the wrong way.